# How can you show that $f$ is one-to-one without horizontal line test?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x) = \sqrt{4x^2 + 1}$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$

I know that typically I can just do the horizontal line test, but I'm confused about how one would do this algebraically.

Comment: Strictly increasing functions are one-to-one. Can you show that it is strictly increasing?

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal line test?

Comment: Show the derivative is nonzero.

Comment: @AndreaMarino the "*horizontal line test*" involves graphing the function, imagining a horizontal line, sliding that line up or down and seeing if there are any such positions for the horizontal line such that it intersects the graph in more than one position... a graphical way of noting where there exist $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$ yet $f(x)=f(y)$

Comment: @JMoravitz: well yes it was a rethorical question for the OP, since formalizing the horizontal line test gives a direct solution :) sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

Algebraic method: for one-one functions, show that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4(x_1)^2 + 1} &= \sqrt{4(x_2)^2 + 1} \\
4(x_1)^2 + 1 &= 4(x_2)^2 + 1 \\
4(x_1)^2 &= 4(x_2)^2 \\
(x_1)^2 &= (x_2)^2 \\
x_1 &= \pm \sqrt{(x_2)^2} \\
&= \pm x_2.
\end{align}
But because $x \geq 0$, we reject the negative root.
So $x_1 = x_2$, thus the function is injective.

Comment: Nice answer! I added parentheses around the variables with subscripts (I think that makes things more readable). If you don't like this however then feel free to roll back my edits.

Comment: @Joe ah, didnt consider that the subscripts and superscripts were stacked on top of one another. I agree the parentheses makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

- The function $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is one-to-one
- The function $x\mapsto 4x+1: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is one-to-one
- The function $x\mapsto x^2: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is one-to-one

Call these functions $f_1, f_2, f_3$. Then your function $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2+1}$ is equal to

$$f(x) = f_1(f_2(f_3(x)))$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you can just show that the function is monotone, then this suffices for the function to be injective.

**Hint 2:** you have to show that the function doesn't change from positive to negative or to negative to positive, then the function will be monotone.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of horizontal line test would be this:

$f(a)=f(b)$ iff $\sqrt{4a^2+1} = \sqrt{4b^2+1}$ iff $4a^2+1 = 4b^2+1$ iff $4a^2 = 4b^2$ iff $a^2=b^2$.

The latter means $a=b$ or $a=-b$. But the domain is nonnegative and so $a=b$.